# method to check if password/keycode match

Tags: java, passwords, keycode

I want to write a simple java program to check whether keycode matches a set of conditions.

This is what I have so far:

```
Scanner keycode = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input keycode");
String key1 = keycode.nextLine();

do {

    if (key1.length() < 6 || key1.length() > 8) {

        System.out.println("must be at least 6 letter and max 8 letter");
        return;
    }

    else {

        boolean upper = false;
        boolean lower = false;
        boolean number = false;

        for (char c : key1.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                upper = true;
            } else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                lower = true;
            } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                number = true;
            }
        }
        if (!upper) {
            System.out.println("must contain at least one uppercase character");
            return;
        } else if (!lower) {
            System.out.println("must contain at least one lowercase character");
            return;
        } else if (!number) {
            System.out.println("must contain at least one number");
            return;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

} while (true);

System.out.println("Input keycode again");
String key2 = keycode.nextLine();

if (key1.equals(key2)) {

    System.out.println("keycode matched");
} else {
    System.out.println("keycode dont match");

}
```

The user is prompted to input a keycode.

The program first checks if it is more than 6 characters and less than 8 characters.

It then checks if it contains a lowercase, uppercase and a number.

I want it to allow user to input the password again if he were to make any mistake rather than doing all over again.

If successful, it will ask the user to input keycode again. If the two keycodes don't match,
the user is allowed to try again. After 3 unsuccessful tries, the system will reply with 'keycode mismatch'.

The part I need assistance in is allowing user to input password if it doesn't fit the requirement and password mismatch. When I enter a password less than 6 characters, I get the following output:

```
must be at least 6 letter and max 8 letter
must be at least 6 letter and max 8 letter
must be at least 6 letter and max 8 letter
must be at least 6 letter and max 8 letter
must be at least 6 letter and max 8 letter
```

Comment: Please format your code without posting. Your last code was also improperly formatted. It is difficult to read your code in this state.

Comment: Again, use a boolean variable say `redo`. And at every place you have used `return`, replace it with `redo = true`. And your while condition should be `while(redo)`;

Comment: you have to scan the password again after displaying the error msg

Comment: My Eclipse IDe told me, that contains "unreachable code" after do- while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `boolean` variable say `redo`. And at every place you have used return, replace it with `redo = true`. And your while condition should be `while(redo)`, which will run until `redo is true`, that it, user hasn't entered correct number.

Also, move your `input` reading line: -

```
String key1 = keycode.nextLine();
```

Inside your do-while loop. And also ,reset your `redo` variable to `false` in the loop, so that it doesn't remain `true` forever.

```
String[] keys = new String[2];  // Since you are reading 2 keys, so size = 2
boolean redo = false;
int count = 0;    // To maintain the number of keys read. should stop at count = 2

do {

    redo = false;
    Scanner keycode =  new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input keycode No: + " + (count + 1));
    String key1 = keycode.nextLine();

    if (key1.length() < 6 || key1.length() > 8) {
        redo = true;

    } else {
        /** Your remaining code **/

        if (!upper) {
            System.out.println("must contain at least one uppercase character");
            redo = true;

        } else if (!lower) {
            System.out.println("must contain at least one lowercase character");
            redo = true;

        } else if (!number) {
            System.out.println("must contain at least one number");
            redo = true;

        } else {
            keys[count++] = key1;  // Enter a new key in array
        }
    }

} while (redo || count < 2);  

if (keys[0].equals(keys[1])) {
    System.out.println("Keys are equal");
}
```

Comment: i got some problem adding code after the do while loop


System.out.println("Input keycode again");
String key2 = keycode.nextLine();

if (key1.equals(key2)) {

    System.out.println("keycode matched");
} else {
    System.out.println("keycode dont match");
getting errors

Comment: yup i am reading the keycode twice.
to check if the first entry match with 2nd one, but doesnt need to go through the check again.
just comparing key1 n key2

Comment: You would have to do this in same while loop. Use a count variable, and if one key is read successfully, increase it by one, and read the next one. If count == 2 break out of loop. Also declare your `key1` and `key2` outside your loop.

Answer (score 2):

use a loop

```
boolean flag=false;
while(flag!=true)
{
    Scanner keycode =  new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input keycode");
    String key1 = keycode.nextLine();
    if (key1.length() < 6 || key1.length() > 8) {

    System.out.println("must be at least 6 letter and max 8 letter");

    } 
    else
    {
         flag=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: while loop is better than do while in this case?

Comment: Shouldn't `while(flag!=true)` be replaced with `while(!flag)`?

Comment: @newbieprogrammer. do-while is better, since you want to run it at least once.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the line `String key1 = keycode.nextLine();` inside the do loop so that the user is queried once every time it is needed. Else, you are just stuck in a loop that will always check the same value again and again.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean redo = false;

do {
    redo = false;
    Scanner keycode =  new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input keycode");
    String key1 = keycode.nextLine();

    if (key1.length() < 6 || key1.length() > 8) {
        redo = true;

    } else {
        /** Your remaining code **/

        if (!upper) {
            System.out.println("must contain at least one uppercase character");
            redo = true;

        } else if (!lower) {
            System.out.println("must contain at least one lowercase character");
            redo = true;

        } else if (!number) {
            System.out.println("must contain at least one number");
            redo = true;
        }

          else{
          System.out.println("Input keycode again");
          String key2 = keycode.nextLine();

          if (key1.equals(key2)) {

           System.out.println("keycode matched");
            } else {
             System.out.println("keycode dont match");

             }

       }

    }

} while (redo);
```

i manage to fit the code inside here , not sure if its the correct method to do so?

Comment: You can use an array of String of size 2, and store the keys read in that array. I'll edit my code.